# Shopping basket: Products with options, how to check if a combination exists?

Tags: sql

I have a bit of a SQL problem that I'm hoping someone can help.

On my website someone can order a product and then options for that products, e.g. they buy a car, and options such as tyres, stereo system.  The customer can add multiple items to their basket for the same main item (a car), but then different options for it, such as:

car, pirelli, b&o
car, michelin, b&o

I have this DB structure to achieve this:

```
orders
----------
order_ref
total


orders_parts
------------
id
order_ref
part_id
quantity


orders_parts_options
--------------------
id
option





orders
------
12345     1000.01



orders_parts
------------
1001   12345     Audi     1
1002   12345     Audi     1



orders_parts_options
--------------------
1001    michelin
1001    b&o
1002    pirelli
1002    b&o
```

So here you can see I have two Audis in my shopping basket, one with michelin, one with pirelli, both with B&O audio systems.  My question; let's say another call is made to add an item to the shopping basket for this order, e.g. another Audi with Michelin and B&O, what SQL would I need to get orders_parts.id of 1001?

I came up with this bit of rubbish:

```
SELECT op.id FROM orders_parts op
    INNER JOIN orders_parts_options opo ON (op.id = opo.id)
WHERE op.order_ref = 12345 AND (opo.option = 'michelin' OR opo.option = 'b&o')
```

But I get this result

```
1001 
1001
1002
```

from that.  I'm guessing I need to aggregate it and have a having count = 2 in there, but just cannot work it out.  Anyone smarter out there who can help me?

(just to add, the DB is normalized in real life, but for clarity I've but full text values in there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT op.id, count(op.id) as n FROM orders_parts op
    INNER JOIN orders_parts_options opo ON (op.id = opo.id)
WHERE op.order_ref = 12345 AND (opo.option = 'michelin' OR opo.option = 'b&o')
GROUP BY op.id;
```

This query retrieves all parts (and their number) for the order_ref=12345 where option = 'michelin' or option = 'b&o'

Comment: Aha, thanks, just needed to add HAVING n=2 and I get the id I'm after as I only wanted the id where it had both of the specified options.